# ORACLE display count to zero, when row is null in column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, zero

I have a table with many of columns, I count the specific names on column and if that name not on list, I want to display it zero, but not get in to list.

```
SELECT Names, COUNT (*)
FROM NAMESTABLE
WHERE names IN
                ('Jenny',
                 'Penny',
                 'George',
                 'James',
                 'Jessica',
                 'Monica',
                 'Erica')
             AND  
adeddate BETWEEN '2014/10/15' AND '2014/10/16' 
GROUP BY names
```

---

```
NAMES  ||   COUNT(*)
Jenny  ||   33
Penny  ||   4
George ||   25
James  ||   87
```

so i want to  Jessica, Monica, Erica as ZERO even these names are not in COLUMN

```
Names    ||  Count(*)
Jenny    ||    33
Penny    ||     4
George   ||    25 
James    ||    87
Jessica  ||     0
Monica   ||     0
Erica    ||     0
```

`nvl(count(*),0)` does not work

Comment: so does namestable have values in it for jessica monica and erica?  if not you're saying you want your filter to add values to your result set when they were not there in the first place?  That's simply not how SQL works. You have to have a table/set with this data in it first.  This could be done via union, cte, or temp tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could group your results by name and then `left join` the result to a table of your names to fill in the blanks:

```
SELECT    rn.name, NVL(cnt, 0)
FROM      (SELECT 'Jenny' AS name FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Penny' FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'George' FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'James' FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Jessica' FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Monica' FROM dual
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Erica' FROM dual) rn
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     namestable
           WHERE    adeddate BETWEEN '2014/10/15' AND '2014/10/16' 
           GROUP BY name) n ON n.name = rn.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you must use other syntax:

```
SELECT t.Names, COUNT(n.Names)
FROM (
  SELECT 'Jenny' AS names FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Penny' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'George' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'James' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jessica' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Monica' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Erica' FROM DUAL
) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN NAMESTABLE n
  ON n.names = t.names AND n.adeddate BETWEEN '2014/10/15' AND '2014/10/16'
GROUP BY t.names
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with a CTE..

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 'Jenny' Names FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Penny' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'George' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'James' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Jessica' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Monica' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Erica' FROM dual)
SELECT CTE.names, coalesce(count(NT.Names),0)
FROM  CTE
LEFT JOIN NAMESTABLE NT 
  on CTE.Names = NT.Names
 and adeddate BETWEEN '2014/10/15' AND '2014/10/16' 
GROUP BY CTE.Names
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an a table containing all valid names, eg valid_names table.  Then join to your namestable using an outerjoin.  Eg:

```
select valid_names.name, count(1) 
from namestable, valid_names
where valid_names.name=namestable.name (+)
group by valid_names.name
order by valid_names.name;
```